# Python PhantomJS: errorMessage":"'undefined' is not a function

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I am using Selenium with PhantomJS driver in Python. I am getting following error:

```
Message: {"errorMessage":"'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'arguments[0].click()')","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"194","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:56304","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/3.5"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"script\": \"arguments[0].click();\", \"args\": [{\"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf\": \":wdc:1489474684803\", \"ELEMENT\": \":wdc:1489474684803\"}], \"sessionId\": \"89d587e0-0883-11e7-9ebc-d3d9bf26e797\"}","url":"/execute","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"execute","directory":"/","path":"/execute","relative":"/execute","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/execute","queryKey":{},"chunks":["execute"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/89d587e0-0883-11e7-9ebc-d3d9bf26e797/execute"}}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

The code I am using is:

```
elem_more = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Suivant")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem_more)
```

The same code works with Firefox driver.

Comment: how about just `elem_more.click()`?

Comment: @Andersson that does not work due to Javascript being called.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether link is static or dynamically created by `JS`... I tried `elem_more.click()` and it works fine with `Firefox`

Comment: @Andersson first off I need to use with `PhantomJs`, second I tried non-JS click version first, it was not clicking at all. I will try again

Comment: @Andersson it is not working.. this is the URL I am accessing(leparking.fr/voiture-occasion/Porsche--targa-g.html#!/voiture-occasion/Porsche--targa-g.html%3Fslider_millesime%3D1940%7C1985)

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue as for me it works on `PhantomJS` both with simple `click()` and `JavaScript` `click()`... Can you share more code? Problem can be somewhere else